# is it ok to write php code in laravel's blade?

Tags: laravel-5

is it ok to write php code in laravel's blade?
this is my code

```
  <?php

    $orders = order::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get(); 
    $counts= $orders->count(); 
    $totalPrice = 0; 

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $counts ; $i++) { 
        $totalPrice += $order->cart->totalPrice; 
    } 

    echo $totalPrice; 

  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Is it possible?** Definitely.

**Should you?** Most probably not. Laravel is based on the MVC pattern, which strives to separate business logic from the views. I think it is way better to use a controller for retrieving the data and passing it to a view, after which you use blade templating in said view to display the data (which in this case just means replacing `<?php echo ... ?>` with `{{ ... }}`)

There are a number of advantages for keeping  the business logic and views separate that you're missing out on, amongst others:

- Reusability, when the view is just used for displaying any generic list of items, it can be used in multiple places. If it contains specific logic like this one, the reusability is hurt a lot. The same goes for the logic, if it were in a separate controller it would be reusable.
- Modularity, when working with Laravel most people will expect business logic to be in a controller (separation of concerns), by putting it in a view you are making it harder to find and you are also requiring the change of a view while it might only be the logic that is changing. Modularity also allows multiple people to work on separate modules at the same time without them having to affect eachother.
- Readability/Clarity, having the logic be in a method (with describing name and documentation) inside a controller (with again a describing name and documentation) will tell another developer what that code does and makes it easier for him to read said code and earlier mentioned view (from which you could call the method).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Longer answer: Blade is a templating engine which renders the view of your application.  Code like that should reside in the modal.  Placing logic into your View is spaghettifying your code and will come back to bite you.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not! because all of this structures designed to split your code logic from the view, this is what we call [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), And the goal of this design is:

> MVC decouples the various components of an application, developers are able to work in parallel on different components without impacting or blocking one another.